# Scenekit detecting User tapped object

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, scenekit

I recently started using scenekit for scenekit in iOS 8. I am facing difficulty in detecting whether the user has tapped or pressed on the object. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation for the [`hitTest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/hitTest:options:) method. Call that from wherever you're handling touch events to get a list of 3D scene objects/locations "under" a 2D screen point.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to get sample code that shows the hitTest in action is to create a sample app using the Game template in XCode6.  Create a new project, select the "Game" template.

The hitTest code should be there in the implementation of:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognize
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a tap gesture to the object and check whether it is a SCNNode()

```
     @objc func tapGestureRec(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil){
            let location: CGPoint = (sender?.location(in: self.view))!
            let hits = self.sceneKitView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
            if let tappedNode : SCNNode = hits.first?.node {
                ...
            }
     }
```